# What do you call somebody who has a profession of answering questions in an on-line question-answer site such as StackExchange?

Tags: questions, professions

How would you present your employment if you are working for a question and answer website like StackExchange (employer) and your job is to answer questions in a specific subject like Physics?

Comment: I didn't know this was a profession/employment. Who is the employer who pays for this?

Comment: You might call yourself a "Physics Stack Exchange [Question] Answerer" which, I'm sure, will open up an interesting conversation.

Comment: Broke, with too much time on their hands. I mean, hey, this is fun—but it's not a profession, because it doesn't pay.  At best, it's a harmless hobby; at worst, an insidious addiction.

Comment: "Harmless drudge" is, I believe, the traditional and preferred term, at least for ELU.

Comment: "Mythical beast" is the proper term.

Comment: I agree with grafitos answer.  The kind of job you are describing is becoming more common now and I think "consultant" fits.  If you were preparing a resume, you would list consultant and then put "answered user questions." under responsibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic term of **on-line consultant** may be preceeded by the speciality, i.e. "Physics".

Comment: You mean "on-line" physics consultant?

Comment: I was thinking at "physics on-line consultant", but your formulation is good as well. I don't know which sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

*Consultant*!

I have been getting quite frustrated with the growing number of people who, when you ask them what they do, say "I'm a consultant" -- and then when you ask them to elaborate, they are incapable of describing what they do in 25 words or less.  So -- jump on the bandwagon!

Answer (score -1):

Such a person might have a job title: "Subject Matter Expert -- Physics" or "Physics Subject Matter Expert".  Another job title might emphasize their role in the on-line community: "Community Leader -- Physics".

There are many other possible titles that are more fanciful and whimsical.  For example: "Physics Guru" or "Oracle of Physics" or "Master Physicist".

Comment: None of these offer any hint that their job is answering questions on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Job titles do not usually mention the employer.  Also job titles are often more general and more abstract than the duties involved.  Thus, "Developer Evangelist" is more general and abstract than the tasks, which basically involve holding meetings, answering questions, going to conferences, etc.

Comment: *Expert* is a title that can only be awarded by others, let alone that it has nothing to do with  a 'profession'.

Comment: @TimLymington There are many job titles that contain words that, outside of that context, would not seem appropriate for self-attribution. Also, there are many companies that have job titles that include: "Subject Matter Expert" or "Expert" in some form, including consulting companies and publishers.

Comment: @MrMeritology could you give some examples of jobs whose titles would not seem appropriate for self attribution?  Being an English teacher I am curious to know if others think I shouldn't be calling myself that.

Comment: @michael_timofeev "Master Carpenter", "<anything> Guru", "<anything> Ninja", "<anything> Rockstar", and "<anything> Wizard".  See: http://www.recruitingblogs.com/profiles/blogs/recruiting-for-gurus-wizards-ninjas-rockstars-and-evangelists

Comment: @MrMeritology master carpenter?  Are you kidding?  That is an actual title that is earned after going through apprentice and journeyman.